# How to upload a folder with its subfolders and files into google drive folder using python

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I used successfully the code below to upload my file into a folder in my google drive:

```
import requests
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer ###youraccesstoken###"} #put ur access token after the word 'Bearer '
para = {
    "name": "dl.jpg", #file name to be uploaded
    "parents": ["####yourdrivefolderid####"] # make a folder on drive in which you want to upload # files; then open that folder; the last thing in present url will be folder id
}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open("./myfile.jpg", "rb") # replace 'application/zip' by 'image/png' #for png images; similarly 'image/jpeg' (also replace your file name)
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files
)
print(r.text)
```

How can I upload a folder instead of a file into my folder in google drive?

Comment: You will need to loop though your folder structure.  When you hit a new directory you will need to a create directory and when its a file you will need to upload the file.

If you are looking for a method which will upload them in one call there isnt one.  I recommend following this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python rather that coding this manually

Comment: I downloaded credentials.json from google drive